# Joint Density of Z

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find the density of $Z$ given that $Z=Y/X$ for $f(xy)=8xy$. Let $x \in [0,1]$ and $y$ is between 0 and $x$. I think this is 
$$\int^1_0\int^{x/4}_0f(x,y)dydx$$

Correct? I do not think it is because I believe I need something in terms of $Z$.

Then if I want to solve for the expected value of $z$, it is $\int^1_0zf(z)dz$, But

Comment: Presumably, this expression gives the probability that $Z < 1/4$, since the area of integration is the portion of the unit square below the line $y = x/4$.

Comment: Could you please clarify?  I am lost on what is being said.

Comment: Draw out the region of the double integral.  What can you say about the value of $Y/X$ for the points in that region?

Comment: it is between .25 and 0

Comment: Exactly!  The double integral thus sums up the probability density over the entire space where the ratio is less than $1/4$, and therefore computes the probability that $Z < 1/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the model of the expression you've given, you could write

$$
\begin{align}
F_Z(z) \equiv P(Z < z) & = \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{zx} f(x, y) \, dy \, dx \\
         & = \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{zx} 8xy \, dy \, dx \\
         & = \int_{x=0}^1 \left. 4xy^2 \right]_{y=0}^{zx} \, dx \\
         & = \int_{x=0}^1 4z^2x^3 \, dx \\
         & = \left. z^2x^4 \right]_{x=0}^1 = z^2
\end{align}
$$

and then

$$
f(z) = \frac{d}{dz} F_Z(z) = 2z \qquad 0 \leq z \leq 1
$$

You should be able to continue on to derive the expected value of $Z$.